# Slim framework - Why does not halt method work if the controller extend the Slim class?

Tags: response, slim

I have seen a very interesting thing. I did a little mvc/rest framework based on the Slim framework.

```
$app->put('/:id', function ($id) {
     $app->halt(500, "Error") // Here this is working.
     (new RestController)->editItem($id);
})->via('put');
```

So I wrote a RestController which extends the BaseController, and my BaseController extends the Slim framework.

```
class BaseController extends \Slim\Slim {

    /**
     * @var \app\models\AbstractModel 
     */
    protected $model;

    public function __construct() {
        $settings = require(__DIR__ .'/../configurations/slim.php');
        parent::__construct($settings);
    }
}
```

So my BaseController can uses the Slim class's methods and properties.

```
class RestController extends BaseController {
    public function editItem($id) {
        $data = $this->getRequestBody();        
        $result = $this->model->update($id, $data['data']);
        // This is absolutely not working, but it seems my application will die in this case.
        // Because I cannot see any written message (with echo or print methods...)
        // This will always return with a 200 staus code and blank page!
        $this->halt(404, json_encode(array('status' => "ERROR")));
    }
}
```

But this will work fine... and I do not get it, why?

```
class RestController extends BaseController {
        public function editItem($id) {
            $data = $this->getRequestBody();        
            $result = $this->model->update($id, $data['data']);
            // This will work.
            $app = Slim::getInstance();
            $app->halt(204, json_encode(array('status' => "ERROR")));
        }
    }
```

Anyone has a good ide?

Answer (score 0):

You construct a new RestController in your route by doing `(new RestController)`. Although it extends Slim/Slim in the class hierarchy, it is a new instance of it; it is not a copy of or reference to `$app`, the Slim application that is actually being run.

This causes issues in the first case: you say `$this->halt(...)` while `$this` is the newly constructed RestController which is a *new instance* of a Slim app, not the one that is currently running. Therefore the halt call has no effect on your the output of your application.

In the second case, you say `$app->halt(...)` where $app is `Slim::getInstance()`, the global instance of your Slim application, which is the actual running Slim app. Therefore the halt call has effect on the output of your application.

You can solve the issue either by using the second approach, or by instantiating your global `$app` variable as a RestController, and then you can do:

```
$app->put('/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
     $app->halt(500, "Error") // Here this is working.
     $app->editItem($id);
})->via('put');
```

**NB**; you forgot to put `use ($app)` in the code posted to your question, I added it in my code above. Is it present in the code you are actually running? Otherwise the `$app->halt()` call should result in an error in any case.